# LINQ - flatten list of objects with child list into one list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class called Activity and this class has a child list of Users. Here is what it looks like:

```
public class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
    }

    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }        
}
```

The user class looks like:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

Using LINQ, I would like to build a "`List<KeyValuePair<string,User>>()`". So for example, if I had a data set that looked like this:

```
var activities = new List<Activity>()
{
    new Activity()
    {
        Number = "ActivityA",
        Users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserA"
            },
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserB"
            },
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserC"
            }
        }
    },
    new Activity()
    {
        Number = "ActivityB",
        Users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserD"
            },
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserE"
            },
            new User()
            {
                Name = "UserF"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What LINQ statement would I need to write in order for my output KeyValuePair list to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Should be :  Name = "UserA", ID = 123

Comment: I have edited it to remove the ID field to avoid confusion

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> results = activity.Users.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(activity.Number, x.Name)).ToList();

Comment: *flatten list of objects with child list into one list*, this mean, you have a list of ``Activity`` not object, for the example?

Comment: Apologies, my question wasn't clear enough. It's now been edited to clarify. Thank you Sijad for the correction advice.

Comment: @cullimorer Did you try your code? `"ActivityA"` string can't be assigned to `int Number`, `"UserD"` string can't be assigned to `int Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectManay` to flatten *list of list* of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to one *list*, like the following code :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs = activities
    .SelectMany(x => x.Users.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Number, y.Name)))
    .ToList();
```

If you want list of `KeyValuePair<string, User>`, use the following code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, User>> keyValuePairs = activities
    .SelectMany(x => x.Users.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, User>(x.Number, y)))
    .ToList();
```

Note that, `Number` of activities considered unique.

`Number` and `Name` must be a `string`.

i hope this will help you out.

Comment: @cullimorer, can you try this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Use a LINQ [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) and [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to transform the objects to new form.

Edited as per the OP's modification.

```
var results = activities.SelectMany(activity => activity.Users.Select(user => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(activity.Number, user.Name))).ToList();
```

Though the Class have the `Name` and `Number` as int but the Data is defined as strings.

Comment: Apologies, my question wasn't clear enough. It's now been edited to clarify.